# Large Scale Personalization - Per User vs Global Models

Tags: classification

I'm currently working on a project that would benefit from personalized predictions.  Given an input document, a set of output documents, and a history of user behavior, I'd like to predict which of the output documents are clicked.

In short, I'm wondering what the typical approach to this kind of personalization problem is.  Are models trained per user, or does a single global model take in summary statistics of past user behavior to help inform that decision?  Per user models won't be accurate until the user has been active for a while, while most global models have to take in a fixed length feature vector (meaning we more or less have to compress a stream of past events into a smaller number of summary statistics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question is going to vary pretty wildly depending on the size and nature of your data. At a high level, you could think of it as a special case of multilevel models; you have the option of estimating a model with complete pooling (i.e., a universal model that doesn't distinguish between users), models with no pooling (a separate model for each user), and partially pooled models (a mixture of the two). You should really read Andrew Gelman on this topic if you're interested.

You can also think of this as a learning-to-rank problem that either tries to produce point-wise estimates using a single function or instead tries to optimize on some list-wise loss function (e.g., NDCG).

As with most machine learning problems, it all depends on what kind of data you have, the quality of it, the sparseness of it, and what kinds of features you are able to extract from it. If you have reason to believe that each and every user is going to be pretty unique in their behavior, you might want to build a per-user model, but that's going to be unwieldy fast -- and what do you do when you are faced with a new user?

Comment: Is this the Gelman paper referenced: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/rsquared.pdf?

Comment: That works, but I highly recommend his [book on multilevel modeling](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/).