# Neural Network: One model per user or (one-hot) variable with one model?

Tags: neural-network

I have about 120 users with a total of 4500 data points. The minimum user has about 5 data points and the maximum has about 100 data points. I would like to build a model that will make predictions for each user.

What is the optimal approach? Do I create a single model for each user or do I create a single model with a categorical variable to specify the user?

I would imagine the single model approach would leverage the correlation between users, but the model per user approach might suffer from not enough data to generalize well.

I would consider a pooling method described here: [possible duplicate](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/640/large-scale-personalization-per-user-vs-global-models), but there is not enough information in the independent variables to distinguish the users from one another, which is why I would have to create a categorical variable to distinguish users. Meaning, there are many users with the same input variables, but systematically different outputs.

The input variables include: arrival time, day of week, and temperature. The output variables include departure time and miles charged.

Comment: Have you considered making a joint model (i.e. one that applies to all users), or does it **have** to be personalized (i.e. separate output for each user)?

Comment: Well, I think there is useful information in the user name as a variable. Otherwise, there will be multiple users with the same arrival time, however, they will have systematically different departure times, which is something I am trying to predict.

Comment: If you want to extract some information from the name (e.g. sex, nationality), I'd suggest doing it at a pre-processing step (e.g. through some rule or regular expressions) and storing that information in a separate variable. Otherwise, if you think your model is sophisticated enough to extract any useful information by itself you can pass the name as a variable. This seems to me like a typical structured ML problem. I don't see why you need every person to have its own variable.

Comment: Is there any other data you can use specify user? I'm saying this because this variation of user data would somewhat account for why distribution is conditional on user.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to train the neural network with all the data. Then take that global model and fine-tune separate models for each individual customer.

This minimizes the cold-start problem for new customers while creating custom predictions for the unique properties of each customer.